# How is this design achieved in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, tabview

How to achieve this design in Flutter?

This is like a custom animated `TabView`.[image: CustomTabView]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "[container_tab_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/container_tab_indicator)" package
install it with `flutter pub add container_tab_indicator`

then use it like this:

```
import 'package:container_tab_indicator/container_tab_indicator.dart';

...

TabBar(
  tabs: [
    Text('Orders', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink[900])),
    Text('Order Requests', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink[900])),
    Text('My Requests', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink[900])),
  ],
  indicator: ContainerTabIndicator(
    //play with these properties as you see fit
    radius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 36),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl-class.html) assuming the application follows the iOS design language.

```
  int? _selectedSegment = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: CupertinoSlidingSegmentedControl(
          groupValue: _selectedSegment,
          onValueChanged: (int? value) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedSegment = value;
            });
          },
          children: const {
            0: Text('Orders'),
            1: Text('Order Requests'),
            2: Text('My Requests'),
          }
      )),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Selected Segment: $_selectedSegment',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can also create a custom tab bar like a below :

https://github.com/Kalpesh209/tab_bar_without_appbar_flutter

make changes as per requirement